# Is there a way to force SimpleImputer to return a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

The following code

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=[1, 2, np.nan],
    y=[2, np.nan, 0]
))

SimpleImputer().fit_transform(df)
```

Returns

```
array([[1. , 2. ],
       [2. , 1. ],
       [1.5, 0. ]])
```

Is there a way to use an imputer that returns a pandas dataframe instead of a numpy array? Is there a scikit-learn implementation for that?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(SimpleImputer().fit_transform(df))`

Comment: The issue with that is that the column names are lost, and this doesn't work well in a scikit-learn pipeline.

Comment: Most code outside of pandas itself uses `df.values`, the array derived from the the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the columns (e.g. for using ColumnTransformers in a later step), you can create a wrapper around `SimpleImputer`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, np.NaN], "B": [3, np.NaN, 4], "C": [np.NaN, 5, 6]})

class PandasSimpleImputer(SimpleImputer):
    """A wrapper around `SimpleImputer` to return data frames with columns.
    """

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.columns = X.columns
        return super().fit(X, y)

    def transform(self, X):
        return pd.DataFrame(super().transform(X), columns=self.columns)


PandasSimpleImputer().fit_transform(df)

>>>
    A   B   C
0   1.0 3.0 5.5
1   2.0 3.5 5.0
2   1.5 4.0 6.0
```

Answer (score 7):

The `SimpleImputer` returns a transformed array, as mentioned in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html). You can either construct a new dataframe, or modify the dataframe in-place with the result from the imputter as:

```
df[:] = SimpleImputer().fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally all the transformation functions in `sklearn` return `numpy` array. You need to get into the habit of using

```
pd.DataFrame(SimpleImputer().fit_transform(df), columns = df.columns)
```

Comment: Is there a way to update inplace using `df.update()`?

Comment: I don't think so. `df.update` takes in a `pandas DataFrame` or `Series` as an argument. But here we are dealing with a `numpy array`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to do this: Use the [set_output](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html) misc method from scikit-learn, like this:

```py
scaler = StandardScaler().set_output(transform="pandas")
```